# Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. 2010 vs 2007

Tags: ms-access, provider

I have seen a lot of questions regarding this but have not found an answer to this question:

We have an application that utilizes Access files. If I have the 2010 Database Access Engine  installed, the application throws the "provider" exception.

If I install 2007 Database Engine, it works. My connection string looks like this:

"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=....."

I cannot figure out why 2007 works but 2010 does not. I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried both for 2010 and got the same result.

Comment: The app is set to run for any CPU with a preference to 32. I turned the preference off and still got the same result. I was told this was a fairly recent issue. It started happening before I started working on this project so I am trying to track this down. Really driving me nuts.